# The Happy Prisoner

Tags: riddle, rhyme

I was the freest man around.
Yet I never left my grounds
(for years at a stretch)
I could walk, fight, or run.
I'm as able-bodied as anyone!
And my riches I can't count!
But I rarely ventured out.
I'm stable mentally and emotionally
And many dream of being me.

Related:

> [A Tail of One Lady](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28818/) (but not the same person.)

Comment: Yah. Riddle and rhyme are a little better fit for tags.

Comment: It's Morgan Freeman!

Comment: @Alex I can see the 'Shawshank Redemption' reference...but he wasn't rich in that movie...

Comment: @manshu million dollar baby / dreamcatcher / another-hundred-movies~

Comment: Alex - put that as an answer. Based on how a tail of one lady is set up, it seems like a pretty likely answer ;)

Comment: @charfellow i tried, but i feel like i'm wrong with some lines, and missing 1.. let's see

Comment: I would tend to think the fact the two posts are *related* would indicate that this isn't a real person... but I'm horrible at puzzles. =)

Comment: @jpmc26 Of course it's a real person.

Comment: Can "I never left my grounds (for years at a stretch)" be interpreted as written, i.e., "I left my grounds (just not very often)"?

Comment: @question_asker That is precisely what it means.

Answer (score 9):

Is it

> Bruce Wayne/Batman

I was the freest man around.

> Bruce Wayne could go wherever, whenever he wanted with his vast wealth. No one accused him of anything.

Yet I never left my grounds
(for years at a stretch)

> After the incidents of *Dark Knight*, he became a recluse.

I could walk, fight, or run.
I'm as able-bodied as anyone!

> Batman was physically fit, and could do just about anything.

And my riches I can't count!

> Vastly wealthy as Bruce Wayne

But I rarely ventured out.

> Again, never left the manor for several years due to shame/guilt/etc.

Comment: [my story](http://i3.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/facebook/000/014/748/The_True_Dark_Knight_by_Shawnzy.jpg)

Comment: Hmmm, interesting guess.

Comment: The addition of the last two lines has kind of killed my answer.

Answer (score 3):

It can be

> Characters of GTA series

---

I was the freest man around.

> Yup, free enough to kill people.

Yet I never left my grounds

> Can't leave the city

I could walk, fight, or run.

> A lot.

I'm as able-bodied as anyone!

> Yeah, in every single game.

And my riches I can't count!

> Cheat codes.

But I rarely ventured out.

> Can't go out of the city.

I'm stable mentally and emotionally
And many dream of being me.

> Depends on the person who is playing the game

Answer (score 3):

Here's my **shot**:

> I do think this answer is more related to sports especially Football rather than movies. Hence my answer is **David Beckham**

I was the freest man around.
Yet I never left my grounds
(for years at a stretch)

> He played the **midfielder** position in Football. Midfielders are the freest men around and travel the longest distance in a Football match. They never leave the ground, or it can be a reference to David's outfield appearance record. [Here's the Wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Beckham)

I could walk, fight, or run.
I'm as able-bodied as anyone!

> I guess its pretty easy to relate these with the answer.

And my riches I can't count!
But I rarely ventured out.
I'm stable mentally and emotionally
And many dream of being me.

> We can say David Beckham is kind of "Richy Rich Rich". Rarely ventured out can again be a reference to his outfield appearance record, and of course he is mentally and emotionally stable (but his OCD keeps me bothering about this mental stability relation). May people do dream about being Beckham.

Answer (score 3):

I will wager a guess that you are:

> Adam

I was the freest man around.

> In his creation story, Adam was the first man on Earth, and was free to do anything except eat from one tree.

Yet I never left my grounds
(for years at a stretch)

> Having everything he could want in the Garden of Eden, Adam had no need to go anywhere.  However, he was eventually forced to leave after the trick of the serpent.

I could walk, fight, or run.
I'm as able-bodied as anyone!

> Again, he was the first man, and made in God's own image, so he was likely able-bodied, even if there were few comparisons available.  He *was* able-bodied enough to have another body, that of Eve, created from his own, but that was *probably* more of God's work than Adam's.

And my riches I can't count!

> God gave man dominion over all other creation, and in Eden, there would be no want, instead plentiful...everything.

But I rarely ventured out.

> He didn't leave the garden.  Though, when he left Eve's side, the serpent tricked her into eating the forbidden fruit and they were both expelled from the garden.

I'm stable mentally and emotionally

> He wasn't crazy, he just became more aware after eating the fruit.  Like seeing he was naked and covering himself, for instance- not crazy.

And many dream of being me.

> I am sure many men would dream of being the only man on Earth, in the paradise of the Garden of Eden, made in God's own image, and with an eternal mate.  Could be worse.

Also, Related:

> https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/28998/11452

Comment: oh my goodness.

Answer (score 2):

**Answer:**

> [Howard Hughes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Howard_Hughes)

**Explanation:**

> He was a famous, wealthy recluse.  As an aeronautics tycoon, billionaire, and pilot; he could fly anywhere in the world that he wanted; but due to mental issues, he stayed locked up in his home.

*Here's a blow-by-blow if you need it:*

I was the freest man around.

> As a rich aviator, he could go anywhere he wanted...

Yet I never left my grounds
(for years at a stretch)

> but became notoriously reclusive in his later years.

I could walk, fight, or run.
I'm as able-bodied as anyone!

> He was not physically disabled, but had psychological (and other) issues that caused him to isolate himself.

And my riches I can't count!

> He was one of the richest men of his time.

But I rarely ventured out.

> He was notoriously reclusive.

Comment: I hate it when the puzzle changes out from under your answer. :(  "I'm stable mentally and emotionally  And many dream of being me." is a new addition and completely invalidates my answer.  Otherwise, I feel like I was right on.

Answer (score 2):

Unlikely, but worth a shot:

> Brian Wilson of the Beach Boys

I was the freest man around.

> Free in his mind anyhow, also free from preconceived notions of what music should be, etc.

Yet I never left my grounds
(for years at a stretch)

> He famously spent 3 straight years in bed

I could walk, fight, or run.
I'm as able-bodied as anyone!

> He never had physical problems, only mental and emotional

And my riches I can't count!

> He's made millions from album sales

But I rarely ventured out.

> He was (and still is to a large degree) very reclusive

Answer (score 1):

You are:

> Morgan Freeman

I was the freest man around.

> "Free"man

Yet I never left my grounds
(for years at a stretch)

> Can't figure this one out

I could walk, fight, or run.

> Wanted

I'm as able-bodied as anyone!

> Invictus?

And my riches I can't count!

> Million Dollar Baby

But I rarely ventured out.

> I'll put the bucket list here

I'm stable mentally and emotionally

> Teachers

And many dream of being me.

> DreamCatcher

Also the title:

> Shawshank Redemption (credit to manshu)

Comment: I considered 'Gordon Freeman' for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

It better not be

> Gordon Freeman

Because

> Howard Hughes is a way better answer. ;P