# A Tail of One Lady

Tags: riddle

I am the luckiest lady around!
I am the most constricted of all.

I am the richest lady on earth!
Yet I own nothing at all.

The world bends to my will!
Yet I possess no power.

Every girl wishes to be in my place!
But I chose not to come and only leave at death.

Who am I?

Related:

> [The Happy Prisoner](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28595)

Also

> The title is a pun, but I doubt anyone will catch it.

Comment: michelle obama?

Comment: @manshu I feel like michelle obama probably owns a couple of things. like probably a car

Comment: @question_asker Unless the government have already provided her with these facilities. (Not sure about USA... But in my country there are these kinds of benefits of being a Prime Minister or President)

Comment: @manshu Oh I'm sure that some of what she uses on a daily basis is provided for her, but she probably still owns stuff from before her husband was president. OK now we're really off topic.

Comment: Why does the related question label this one "A Tail of Two Ladies" in its link to this question?

Comment: @feelinferrety those 2 questions are probably co-related?

Comment: @feelinferrety Check the edits on this question- looks like the title was changed from "Two" to "One" ladies.  No clue why the link hasn't updated on the other side, but I'm no computer whisperer.

Comment: Actually, the presidential family is given relatively little by the government.  The president has to pay the white house staff out of his salary.

Comment: Is this *also* a real person? And by real person, can we assume you mean, you know, a real person, and not some weird sneaky definition that doesn't mean that?

Comment: @question_asker I intend a very real, normal, female human being. But Paul Evan's answer is also fantastic.

Comment: @LN6595 Agreed!

Comment: @user247327 OK well that's definitely not true.

Answer (score 23):

You're:

> Lady Luck.

I am the luckiest lady around!

> Self explanatory.

I am the most constricted of all.

> You're completely **constricted** by the laws of probably.

I am the richest lady on earth!

> All riches come from some sort of luck. Even if you're born into it, your birth alone had some luck involved.

Yet I own nothing at all.

> Luck has no possessions.

The world bends to my will!

> Everything, right down to quantum mechanics has some factor (however large or small) of probability/luck involved.  Even the earth's orbit has a slight wobble to it's **bend** around the sun do to probability.

Yet I possess no power.

> But luck itself doesn't have any power.  It disperses energy in a random manner.

Every girl wishes to be in my place!

> All girls (and boys) want to be the lucky one.

But I chose not to come and only leave at death.

> Luck doesn't **chose** to do anything and when you're dead "your *luck* is up".

Pun:

> The title and hint refer to this being a story (**tale**) of Lady Luck and the luck of heads or **tail**s in a coin toss.  You might not **catch it** (the coin, riddle or pun) if you're *unlucky*.

Comment: Good answer! For the last one (leave at death) it's not so much that it's "up" as it has "run out".

Comment: @Samthere Yes, I suppose it's down to colloquialisms.  "your *luck's* run out" works too.

Answer (score 5):

You could be

> Queen Elizabeth II

I am the luckiest lady around!
I am the most constricted of all.

> Many people consider coins good luck, her portrait is on British coinage. As a portrait on a coin she cannot go anywhere so she is very restricted. Also, she herself is lucky to be the queen, but she is restricted in the things she can do by her station.

I am the richest lady on earth!
Yet I own nothing at all.

> Again, as a portrait on a money, she "has" lots of money yet doesn't own it. Also, as queen she is wealthy, yet her wealth ultimately belongs to the British nation.

The world bends to my will!
Yet I possess no power.

> The world's behavior is influenced by the money with her portrait on it. Yet as queen, she's a figurehead that doesn't have political power.

Every girl wishes to be in my place!
But I chose not to come and only leave at death.

> Every girl dreams of being the Queen. However, the Queen was born into her position and didn't choose it, and will be Queen until her death.

The title is a pun, but I doubt anyone will catch it.

> The "tail" in the title refers to the coins that bear her image. Also "catch it" might be referring to catching a coin after it is flipped in the air.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, nice answer!

Comment: Can I ask why you chose specifically Queen Elizabeth II? Your reasoning seems to apply to many queens.

Comment: I chose her because she is the current Queen, and since the riddle states 1 person I thought I should be more specific than "Queen of England". I assumed she fits best as her picture appears more than other queens on modern currency (though like I said, this is an assumption that I didn't research extensively).

Comment: The question is in the present tense, too

Answer (score 4):

It better not be

> Chell (from the Portal series).

I am the luckiest lady around!
I am the most constricted of all.

> Only person around.

I am the richest lady on earth!
Yet I own nothing at all.

> Again, only person around.  Unlike most video game characters, has zero inventory space.

The world bends to my will!
Yet I possess no power.

> She has no poowers, but bends the world with her portal gun.

Every girl wishes to be in my place!
But I chose not to come and only leave at death.

> She chose not to come to the party with cake, she is in the facility against her will, and only leaves when either she or the boss dies.

A Tail of One Lady

> She has a ponytail.
> Also, didn't she get mocked for being born with a tail?  I can't remember.

Answer (score 4):

In line with my answer on the related question, I think you are:

> Eve

I am the luckiest lady around!

> Eve was blessed by God to enjoy the pleasures of life and Earth, but you could call His blessing luck.  Plus, being made from a rib is pretty lucky.

I am the most constricted of all.

> She was tempted by the serpent.  Some serpents are constrictors.

I am the richest lady on earth!
Yet I own nothing at all.

> Eve was the first woman in her creation story, so she could claim anything she liked.  However, the world (and Eve) were really God's creation.

The world bends to my will!
Yet I possess no power.

> God gave man (and *wo*man) dominion over all creatures that crawled the Earth, though neither Adam nor Eve possessed any especial powers themselves.

Every girl wishes to be in my place!
But I chose not to come and only leave at death.

> Eve was the only woman on Earth, and had all to herself an  <s>Abel</s> *ahem*, able partner, as well as a garden of paradise to seemingly enjoy forever.  Her expulsion from the garden was the first fall from grace of mankind.  Outside the garden, Adam and Eve would be exposed to pains, trials, and death.

Who am I?

> Eve

Related:

> https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/28997/11452